# CMS Block Widgets for Individual Products

Tags: product, template, cms, static-block, widget

I'm working on a CMS Block to show featured products on the home page. I set up my own template file which loads `$this->getProduct()` for the data.

The problem I'm having is that I'm using the `catalog/product_view` block type and it only loads one product, so if I repeat the widget multiple times with multiple product IDs, it will only repeat the first one (I'm guessing because the class constructor gets the product in the constructor, and Magento won't load it more than once per request)

For example, this:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_view" product_id="1234" template="page/html/featured/product.phtml"}}
{{block type="catalog/product_view" product_id="5678" template="page/html/featured/product.phtml"}}
```

When repeated twice will display the product with ID 1234 twice, using this code:

app/design/frontend/mypackage/page/html/featured/product.phtml

```
<?php 
$p = $this->getProduct();
$img = $p->getImageUrl();
$description = $p->getShortDescription();
$name = $p->getName();
$link = $p->getProductUrl();

echo "<div style='display:inline-block;width: 20%;float: left;'>
        <a href ='$link'><img style='width:80%;margin:0 10%;' src='$img' />
        <div class='product-name'>$name</div>
        </a>
        <div class='home-product-description'>$description</div>
    </div>";
```

Is there a different block type (model) that I can use to load individual products, perhaps as a singleton? I would like to be able to get a different product for each time I call the widget using the same template to display the output. The only other option I could think of was to load a collection of a specified category in the template itself, but naturally that defeats the purpose of flexibility that the CMS offers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*There's a widget for that!* In your CMS page,

```
{{widget type="catalog/product_widget_link"
         anchor_text="[Optional: CUSTOM LINK TEXT]"
         template="catalog/product/widget/link/link_block.phtml"
         id_path="product/223552"}}
```

Then customize app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/widget/link/link_block.phtml. I use something like this:

```
<?php

$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_image = '';
$_price = '$' . money_format('%n', $_product->getFinalPrice());

if ($_product) {
    $_image = Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')
        ->keepAspectRatio(true)
        ->keepFrame(true)
        ->resize(115,115)
        ->__toString();
}
?>
<div class="item">
    <a <?php echo $this->getLinkAttributes() ?>>
        <img src="<?php echo $_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAnchorText()); ?>" style="border:0" />
        <?php echo nl2br($this->htmlEscape($this->getAnchorText())); ?><br />
        <b><?php echo $_price; ?></b>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I had found this widget and was trying to figure out how to use it since the default just created a hyperlink. Then I saw it was using the product title for the hyperlink text. What I ended up doing was: since our product titles are the exact same as the SKU, I used that to start a Mage_Core_Model_Product object and loaded the product by sku, and this did the trick as well. As far as your solution, if I call this widget multiple times will it have the same behavior as explained in the question? e.g calling $_product = $this->getProduct() would only call the first product?

Comment: I noticed that was happening when I used $this->getProduct() as mage only seems to want to load that once. In any event, the issue is resolved and I'll go ahead and mark this as the answer.

Comment: No, it'll grab a new product each time

Comment: Nice, I may have to use this instead then for the sake of performance and ram. There shouldn't be any need to create another object if it already exists. Thanks again!

Comment: Is there anyway to pass in multiple product ids? I would like to display a grid of products but don't want to target them by category id like I see in all other tutorials.

Comment: @LouisW No, only one product id per widget block. If you use this widget you'll have to put them into a grid yourself.