# Adding individual products to CMS pages

Tags: magento-1.9, cms-block

I have been looking for a solution to display individual products on a CMS page.  I found [this link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11674/cms-block-widgets-for-individual-products) on Magento exchange, and also [this other link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3029283/magento-display-individual-products), but they both break the page!

Is there any other solution to add up to 8 products to a CMS page?

Answer (score 2):

You could add products from a certain category using the following in your cms page editor:

```
{{block type="catalog/product_list" name="home.catalog.product.list" alias="products_cms" category_id="about us products ID" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}
```

You could then add a category for the cms page products, for example - create category "about us products" and then add that category id to the widget code.

This way you can easily manage cms displayed products from the category section, rather than hardcoding individual product IDs.

Comment: @Bobadew Thanks for the reply.  The problem with that solution is if you have 100s of CMS pages with **different products** on *each CMS page*, then you would have to create 100s of different categories for that purpose and I don't think that's efficient.  I think this might possible to achieve on the CMS page, without adding new categories?

Comment: If you cant use the category approach maybe something like the accepted answer here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/11674/cms-block-widgets-for-individual-products use the default widget and modify its template to meet your needs

Answer (score 1):

I have searched the whole afternoon without much luck. 
Finally I found this free extension works well for me: 
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/block-of-selected-products.html

It enables you to insert selected products using simple widget.
Hope this can help you.